# getting record from rowEdit in mvc extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using the rowEditing on my grid in my mvc application. I'm able to handle the event when the user clicks update. However i'm having issues get the selected record. The below behaves strangely. I do not get the record.data.Name value the first time i click update. Tho i can see the value in fire bug. [image]

```
init: function () {

        this.control({
         'button[text=Update]': {
            click: this.onMaterialUpdate
        }
  });

},

onLaunch: function () {

},
onMaterialUpdate: function (button) {

    var grid = Ext.getCmp('materialsContainer');
    var record= grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];


    if (record != null) {
        console.log(record.data.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it... but I think the click event happens before completeEdit, thus the record is neither committed, nor updated in the grid (or its selection).

Perhaps try to capture the edit event of the row editor instead of click? You should get the correct record there?

Comment: i think your on the right track. I tried completeEdit: this.onMaterialUpdate. But it wasn't called in the init. I also tried "edit"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggested handle edit event of the RowEditor plugin. You could subscribe to this event on grid render event for example. By getting the plugin by pluginId.